# Microsoft mouse screws up my power settings

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, mouse, power-management

Running a new computer with Windows 7 and 64-bit OS. Had a wireless Logitech mouse that worked perfectly with this set up. The mouse was old, and the buttons were sticking and causing double clicks, so I bought a new Microsoft Mobile Wireless 3000 mouse to replace it. The new mouse works perfectly, but now my screen saver is disabled and my computer won't go into sleep mode after 15 minutes as per my power setting. If I hook the Logitech mouse back up, screen saver works fine and computer goes to sleep as it should. Am I missing something, or is Microsoft's mouse just junk. Got no software with the new mouse, so no drivers seem available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the IntelliPoint drivers from [Microsoft's hardware downloads page](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/downloads/default.mspx). This should give you a fully featured driver.

I've had no problems with it and the screen saver kicks in whether running XP or Windows 7.